# How to run the stored procedure that has OUTPUT parameter from C#?

Tags: c#

I have a stored procedure with an output parameter. How do I read this value using C# code?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: I'd upvote this because it's a useful question, but because of lack of "I tried this" I can't do so.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I assume you use ADO.NET? If so, the SqlParameter class has the property "Direction". Set direction to output and after the query has executed you read the value from that parameter.

Something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@pkid", SqlDbType.Int);
    parm.Value = 1;
    parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

    SqlParameter parm2 = new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parm2.Size = 50;
    parm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // This is important!
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: i have another question i need to determine that output parameter
is decimal(8,2) how!!!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If you are returning a decimal in the output variable you should set the SqlDbType to Decimal. If you are in fact returning a decimal you can cast like this: (decimal)cmd.Parameters[@"MyDecimal"].Value

Comment: I would strongly suggest to put `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(....) { ... }` blocks as a best practice

Comment: i have problem when call stroc embeded  or execution nested stroc