# how to read the parameters defined in declare statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql

In one of my c# projects I want to read the parameters defined in declare statement from the following procedure.

```
create procedure [dbo].[TestRecordSelectMInfo2]
@GRNo varchar(4)
as 
declare 
@SName varchar(35),
@Class Varchar(15)
begin
Select @SName = Students.SName, @Class = Class.Class from Students inner join Class on Students.ClassId = Class.ClassId where Students.GRNo = @GRNo
end
```

How can I read The values of @SName and @Class using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alter your procedure like this

```
create procedure [dbo].[TestRecordSelectMInfo3]
@GRNo varchar(4),
@SName varchar(35) output,
@Class Varchar(15) output
as 
begin
Select @SName = Students.SName, @Class = Class.Class from Students inner join Class on Students.ClassId = Class.ClassId where Students.GRNo = @GRNo
end
```

USAGE:

```
private void GetData()
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GRNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbgrno.Text;
            SqlParameter SName = new SqlParameter("@SName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter Class = new SqlParameter("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            Class.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SName.Size = 35;
            Class.Size = 15;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(SName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Class);
            dm.ExectNonActQuery("TestRecordSelectMInfo", cmd);
            tbsname.Text = cmd.Parameters["@SName"].Value.ToString();
            tbclass.Text = cmd.Parameters["@Class"].Value.ToString();
        }
        public void ExectNonActQuery(string spname, SqlCommand command)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string");
            cmd = command;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = spname;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of variables in that stored procedure doesn't make sense. I think you are over-complicating this.

Just change your select statement to this and they will be returned from the stored procedure to the calling code in the resulting recordset.

```
Select Students.SName, Class.Class 
FROM Students inner join Class on Students.ClassId = Class.ClassId 
WHERE Students.GRNo = @GRNo
```

If you really must return a parameter (and I don't think you do). You can define the variable as an output parameter from the stored procedure [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433715/30018).

Comment: I know how to do that... the given procedure is only for an example. The actual pro is a little lengthy that's why a changed it to a simple one. I must set Students.SName and Class.Class in a veriable and that read it. would you like me to post the actual coding in my question?????

Comment: Actually, you probably don't need to do that. It is very uncommon. In any case, I edited my answer in case you insist on doing it that way, which I don't advise.

Comment: The whole part about the output parameter.... Please at least put some effort into this if you expect people to help you.