# How to get a specific parameter value from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am a bit stuck here. I have created a stored procedure which gets all the result on the basis of `AccountID` from different tables. I also want to get a specific parameter `AffinityID` through this stored procedure along with others.

In order to get this, I have made use of the Data Director and it works fine if I add an OUTPUT parameter `AffinityID` in the stored procedure and then in my code use the property `AddOutParameter` to get the `AffinityID`. But I don't want to use the `DataDirector`and not the output parameter.

How will I get the specific value of `AffinityId` with the help of `AccountID`.

The stored procedure is as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAffinityIDByAccountID]
    @AccountID INT= NULL

AS
SELECT 
    acct.AcctID, 
    lua.AffinityID,
    bws.DocumentTypeSettingsID,
    bws.DocumentTypeID,
    bws.AddAccountAttachment,
    bws.SaveAtLocation,
    bws.SaveLocation,
    bws.AddAccountNote,
    bws.NoteReasonID,
    bws.NoteText,
    bws.SendEmail,
    bws.EmailToAddress,
    bws.EmailFromAddress,
    bws.EmailSubject,
    bws.EmailBody
FROM BWSDocumentTypeSettings bws 
Join luAffinity lua on bws.AffinityID=lua.AffinityID
    Join AFFINITYGROUP ag on ag.AffinityID=lua.AffinityID
    join Applicant a on ag.AffGroupID=a.AffGroupID
    join APPLICANTACCOUNT aa on a.ApplID=aa.ApplID
    join Account acct on aa.AcctID=acct.AcctID   
WHERE acct.AcctID=COALESCE(@AccountID, acct.AcctID)
```

I can add an output parameter `AffinityID` here to get the `AffinityID`. But I don't want to use it. How will I get the specific parameter value??

Comment: Do you need to get the id at the same time, or do you just need the procedure be able to  be used in both scenarios? In case of the latter, you could make it a udf instead of a stored procedure and do an executescalar on a select acctid?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. ADO.NET doesn't have a feature called Data Director. What are you talking about? Anyway, if you want to return data from a stored procedure you can either return one or more result sets or use output parameters. What's wrong with output parameters?

Comment: @HimanshuNegi I can second on this. There is no such thing as Data Director in ADO .NET. Did you intend ParameterDirection?

Comment: Yes Data Director does not exists in ADO.NET. Its just a third party tool used..

Comment: How will I achieve it with the help of Results set. I dont want to use OUTPUT parameters.

Comment: I don't get it. You talk about a parameter called AffinityID, but that's a field already returned by your query. In C# you read that value using a SqlDataReader reading the values at index 1 (second value in the returned record) or, if you fill a datatable using a SqlDataAdapter you get it in the DataTable.Rows[0]["AffinityID"]. Could you show the code that calls the stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run the stored procedure that has OUTPUT parameter from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433694/how-to-run-the-stored-procedure-that-has-output-parameter-from-c)