# SQL retrieving OUTPUT into a asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a SQL stored procedure that OUTPUTs the number to a row after I insert of few records. The query works great and returns what I need, although. I would like to take the output from the query and read it into a label. Can someone shine a little light? Thanks.

```
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@spName", txt_Name.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@spSource", txt_Source.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@spDateCreated", txt_DateCreated.Text));

            paramReturnNumber = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            paramReturnNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usps_InsertIntoMedia]
@spName varchar(100),
@spSource varchar(100),
@spDateCreated datetime
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
DECLARE @out nvarchar
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Media (Name, Source, DateCreated)
OUTPUT inserted.Number 
VALUES(@spName,@spSource,@spDateCreated )   

Select @out = Media.Number
FROM Media  
END
```

Comment: Jeff try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433694/how-to-run-the-stored-procedure-that-has-output-parameter-from-c

Comment: Jon it gives me Procedure or function usps_InsertIntoMedia has too many arguments specified.

Comment: should I loop them to be injected if the parameter is input and write to lbl if output?

Comment: You have to specify it as an output parameter, you are passing too many arguments.

Comment: Mark this as your answer, I just went through my query and got it. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to specify the OUTPUT parameter using the SET statment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following technique:

```
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    foreach (SqlParameter sqlp in cmd.Parameters)
    {
         if ((sqlp.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput) || 
             (sqlp.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output))
         {
             ht.Add(sqlp.ParameterName, sqlp.Value);
         }
    }
    <lblName>.Text = (string)ht["@out"];
```