# SQL SERVER 2005 return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi all I have the following stored procedure

```
@UserName varchar(150),
    @UserEmail varchar(300),
    @UserPassword varchar(150), 
    @ContactNumber varchar(150),
    @ContactMobile varchar(150),
    @AreaOfCountry varchar(150),
    @UserId int OUTPUT,
    @AllreadyReg int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --DECLARE @UserId int, @AllreadyReg int
    IF (SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM Users WHERE (UserName = @UserName) OR (UserEmail = @UserEmail)) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @UserId = 0
        SET @AllreadyReg = 1    
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Users (UserName,UserEmail,UserPassword,ContactNumber,ContactMobile,AreaOfCountry) VALUES (@UserName,@UserEmail,@UserPassword,@ContactNumber,@ContactMobile,@AreaOfCountry)
        SELECT @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        SET @AllreadyReg = 0    

    END
```

however when I use it using c# and asp.net its not returning anything, however when I just execute it it does have a results @UserId and @AllreadyReg but the return value is 0 and a single field.

my c# code is below but it never has any rows

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            Response.Write("Line 61");
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_Register", con))
            {
                Response.Write("line 64");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TxtUsername.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", TxtEmail.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", TxtPassword.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", TxtPhone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactMobile", TxtMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaOfCountry", TxtAreaOfCountry.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllreadyReg", ParameterDirection.Output);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Response.Write("line 78");
                    etc etc
```

can anyone help

thanks

Comment: Can you show us the c# code that's calling it?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `ExecuteReader` - your stored proc doesn't generate a *resultset* - it places its responses in output parameters. Marc's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19930816/15498) shows how it should be done.

Comment: if you want to get output parameter you can refer to [This answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433694/how-to-run-the-stored-procedure-that-has-output-parameter-from-c

Comment: btw - if the command *did* generate a result set, you should use `using` around the reader. It doesn't apply in this case because there *is no resultset*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the edit: the mistake is using `ExecuteReader` on a command *that doesn't select a data  grid* - that should be done with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

---

The important thing here is how the parameter is added. For example:

```
var alreadyReg = cmd.CreateParameter();
alreadyReg.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
alreadyReg.ParameterName = "AllreadyReg";
alreadyReg.DbType = DbType.Int32;
cmd.Parameters.Add(alreadyReg);
//...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//...
int val = (int)alreadyReg.Value;
```

Depending on the type of `DbCommand` object, there may be an overload that accepts all of these in one line - the above assumes just `DbCommand`. With `SqlCommand`, you can simplify a bit:

```
var alreadyReg = cmd.Parameters.Add("AllreadyReg", SqlDbType.Int);
alreadyReg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
//...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//...
int val = (int)alreadyReg.Value
```

Comment: I understand what your saying but the if(reader.HasRows) is always null

Comment: @andrewslaughter I would expect that - this query doesn't `SELECT` anything. Look carefully - you'll see I'm using `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Brilliant, you were half right in that it doesn't select anything. Ive modified it a bit and added this to the end of the stored procedure SELECT @UserId,@AllreadyReg which then works great

Comment: @andrewslaughter it would have been fine with output parameters too... and slightly more efficient too. But making them a `select` works too

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", ParameterDirection.Output);
```

wrong usage of [AddWithValu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)e. The second parameter is parsed as parameter value, not direction type. Use proper parameter contructor and the add the result to collection.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already handled it, but just in case, make sure to specify direction of parameter in c# code.