# MS SQL Stored Procedure not returning value (or java needs to alter?)

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Can someone help me here i have a stored procedure which is not returning any value when i run the SP

Running as - so in my java code i'm doing (`exec TestSP(?)` with setting 1 input parameter:

on MS SQL Console running as:

```
exec TestSP @ErrorDescription=''
```

On both grounds i get nothing back.

i get no output just Command completed successfully, any idea what i need to change to make this stored procedure return a value?

--TestSP

```
USE [TESTDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Testtbl] @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(40) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @status INT
    SET @status = (
                    SELECT status
                        FROM Testtbl
                  )
    IF @status = 0
        SET @ErrorDescription = 'OK'
    ELSE
        SET @ErrorDescription = 'FAIL'
    RETURN @status
```

is there anything i need to change at java level to make this work or SP needs to be change?

Java:

```
stmt = connection.prepareCall(sql);
stmt.setString(1, errorDesc);
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.executeUpdate();
String result = stmt.getString(2);

System.outprintln("Result is: "+result);
```

what changes need to be done at java level to make it work, i'm getting no result in variable "result"?

Comment: Is your problem with receiving the *status* value, the *error description* or both?

Comment: my problem is with returning status value. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`RETURN` keyword is not used for returning a value. To return you need `SELECT` statement or `OUTPUT` variable.

Read `RETURN` Documenation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

instead of `RETURN @status` you need `SELECT @status`

Below is correct example of using `OUTPUT`

```
CREATE PROC testSP
    (
        @pOut VARCHAR(40) OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @something INT = 1;

        IF @something = 0
            SET @pOut = 'Zero'

        IF @something = 1
            SET @pOut = 'One'
    END
```

---

```
DECLARE @outparam VARCHAR(10)
EXEC testSP @pOut = @outparam OUTPUT
SELECT @outparam
```

as you can see `OUTPUT` parameter need to be set to some value. If you don't specify `OUTPUT` it will be treated as input

Answer (score 0):

To get a return value you need to assign it to a variable.

To get an output parameter, you need to add the output keyword when calling the procedure

ie:

```
declare @ret int, @ErrorDescription varchar(50)
exec @ret = TestSP @ErrorDescription output
select @ret,  @ErrorDescription
```

Comment: when you say: you need to add the output keyword when calling the procedure - what do you mean - all i'm expecting to do is

exec TestSP @ErrorDescription = '' 

and i expect status value back - if SP needs to be modified let me know what needs changing!

Comment: You should call it as detailed in the answer.

Comment: you cant do that in java or C# like that you have to execute as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: You have to mark the parameter as an output parameter in the calling language, eg: C#.

Comment: ok on out parameter, but i'm looking to get "@status" out from SP not error Description which i believe is the Out parameter. what needs to be changed on SP to make Status returned when simply executed?

Comment: It is. The problem is with how you're calling it

Comment: sorry what you mean it is? are you implying SP is fine and C# needs to call it differently?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Look at the Direction property on the parameter

Comment: can you give me any examples for calling SP like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433694/how-to-run-the-stored-procedure-that-has-output-parameter-from-c